# Matlab: Delay in displaying messages in parallel threads with fileSystemWatcher

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, filesystemwatcher

I need to figure out why there is a delay in the display of the messages in the code below. I have tracked the delay to the spmdReceive() in spmdIndex ==2 and 3, but I am not sure what to do next. The point of the code is to get notified from the FileSystemWatcher when there is a renamed, deleted, or created event and act on that event. However, I have to create two events in order for the thread to pick up the previous one.

Example, if I create "file1.txt", thread 3 is supposed to display that a message like "Worker 3 received: Analysis: file1.txt fom worker 1" immediately. However, I have to create another file (like "new file.txt") to have thread 3 display the message that was supposed to show up previously ("Worker 3 received: Analysis: file1.txt fom worker 1").
The message displayed on the Matlab command line is always one behind, and it applies to both threads (meaning the same thing is happening in thread 2 with the rename/delete action).

```
function testScript()
    spmd
        if spmdIndex == 1
            try
                fswObj = System.IO.FileSystemWatcher('C:\Waves2');
                fswObj.Filter = '*.*';
                fswObj.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName;
                fswObj.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                addlistener(fswObj,'Renamed',@notifyThread);
                addlistener(fswObj,'Deleted',@notifyThread);
                addlistener(fswObj,'Created',@notifyThread);
                ii = 1;
                while true
                    pause(.5); ii = ii+1;
                    if mod(ii,10) == 0
                        disp('loop')
                    end
                end
            catch ME
                fid = fopen('error.txt','w');
                fprintf(fid,ME.message);
                fprintf(fid,[num2str(ME.stack(1).line), ' : ', ME.stack(1).name, ' : ',  ME.stack(1).file]);
                fclose(fid);
            end
        elseif spmdIndex == 2
            while true
                disp(datetime('now'))
                [data, source] = spmdReceive(1);
                disp(['Worker 2 received: ', data, ' from worker ', num2str(source)]);
            end
        else
            while true
                disp(datetime('now'))
                [data, source] = spmdReceive(1);
                disp(['Worker 3 received: ', data, ' from worker ', num2str(source)]);
            end
        end
    end
end
function notifyThread(src,event)
    filename = char(event.Name);
    eventTypeFromNotify = char(event.ChangeType.ToString);
    if strcmp(eventTypeFromNotify, 'Renamed')
        disp(datetime('now'))
        spmdSend(['Rename: ' filename],2)
    end
    if strcmp(eventTypeFromNotify, 'Deleted')
        disp(datetime('now'))
        spmdSend(['Delete: ' filename],2)
    end
    if strcmp(eventTypeFromNotify, 'Created')
        disp(datetime('now'))
        spmdSend(['Analysis: ' filename],3)
    end
end
```